# Sending emails from a windows forms application

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, smtpclient

I'm building a windows forms application that's supposed to run on a remote/isolated machine and send error notifications by email to the admins. I've tried employing `System.Net.Mail` classes to achieve this but I'm running into a strange problem:

**1.** I get an error message:

```
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.--->
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by 
the remote host at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, 
Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags) at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.
Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
```

**2.** I tried sniffing the network activity to see what was going wrong. So here's how it goes:

```
i) The DNS lookup for my SMTP server's hostname works
ii) My application connects to the SMTP server and sends "EHLO MY-HOSTNAME"
iii) SMTP server responds back with it's usual
iv) My application sends "AUTH login abcdxyz" and receives an acknowledgement packet
```

At this point, it seems that either the SMTP server doesn't seem to request for the password or my machine shuts off the connection to the SMTP server before the SMTP server could request for a password.

I've tried using different SMTP ports and SMTP hosts. Also, I tried disabling my firewall and AV, but no luck. While connecting to my SMTP server using PuTTY and issuing the same sequence of commands as my application does (picked from the packet sniffer), everything works out fine and I'm able to send out the email.

Here's the code that I'm using:

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Function SendMail() As Boolean

     Dim smtpClient As New SmtpClient("smtp.myserver.com", 587) 'I tried using different hosts and ports
     smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
     smtpClient.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username@domain.com", "password")
     smtpClient.EnableSsl = True 'Also tried setting this to false

     Dim mm As New MailMessage
     mm.From = New MailAddress("username@domain.com")
     mm.Subject = "Test Mail"
     mm.IsBodyHtml = True
     mm.Body = "<h1>This is a test email</h1>"
     mm.To.Add("someone@domain.com")

     Try
          smtpClient.Send(mm)
          MsgBox("SUCCESS!")
     Catch ex As Exception
          MsgBox(ex.InnerException.ToString)
     End Try

     mm.Dispose()
     smtpClient.Dispose()

     Return True

End Function
```

Any advice?

Comment: Added the code into my post...

Comment: If you use this code and use your gmail account credentials for example do you receive the same error? just like Diogo mentions...

Comment: I tried using a different connection and don't seem to have problems with that. As for the connection with which I'm having trouble, I'm able to connect to all SMTP ports using telnet but the connection gets dropped when my app connects to the SMTP server.

Comment: Hey Dude Please See SHAIKRAFFI Code You Can Solve All Problems

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C# it works like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff");
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff");
        List<MailAddress> cc = new List<MailAddress>();
        cc.Add(new MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff"));
        SendEmail("Want to test this damn thing", from, to, cc);
    }

    protected void SendEmail(string _subject, MailAddress _from, MailAddress _to, List<MailAddress> _cc, List<MailAddress> _bcc = null)
    {
        string Text = "";
        SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient("Mailhost");
        MailMessage msgMail;
        Text = "Stuff";
        msgMail = new MailMessage();
        msgMail.From = _from;
        msgMail.To.Add(_to);
        foreach (MailAddress addr in _cc)
        {
            msgMail.CC.Add(addr);
        }
        if (_bcc != null)
        {
            foreach (MailAddress addr in _bcc)
            {
                msgMail.Bcc.Add(addr);
            }
        }
        msgMail.Subject = _subject;
        msgMail.Body = Text;
        msgMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailClient.Send(msgMail);
        msgMail.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Do not forget the `using System.Net.Mail;`

I Think in VB it works like this to, here is the code, it might have some errors, I don't often write in vb.net:

```
Private Sub btnTest_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
    Dim _from As New MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff")
    Dim _to As New MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff")
    Dim cc As New List(Of MailAddress)
    cc.Add(New MailAddress("Someone@domain.topleveldomain", "Name and stuff"))
    SendEmail("Wan't to test this thing", _from, _to, cc)
End Sub

Protected Sub SendEmail(ByVal _subject As String, ByVal _from As MailAddress, ByVal _to As MailAddress, ByVal _cc As List(Of MailAddress), Optional ByVal _bcc As List(Of MailAddress) = Nothing)

    Dim Text As String = ""
    Dim mailClient As New SmtpClient("Mailhost")
    Dim msgMail As MailMessage
    Text = "Stuff"
    msgMail = New MailMessage()
    msgMail.From = _from
    msgMail.To.Add(_to)
    For Each addr As MailAddress In _cc
        msgMail.CC.Add(addr)
    Next
    If _bcc IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each addr As MailAddress In _bcc
            msgMail.Bcc.Add(addr)
        Next
    End If
    msgMail.Subject = _subject
    msgMail.Body = Text
    msgMail.IsBodyHtml = True
    mailClient.Send(msgMail)
    msgMail.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Do not forget to import `System.Net.Mail`

Comment: Thanks Thanatos, but this does not differ much from my code or from what Diogo posted. The problem seems to be that the SMTP server closes the connection when Visual Studio connects to it over a cable connection that I'm using (no issues connecting to SMTP ports using the same cable connection and a different SMTP or Telnet client). But if I connect using a different connection (my secondary is a 3G), Visual Studio doesn't seem to have any problems.

Comment: Did you try using the SendAsync method? it might work with that when it was cause of a Timeout. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h#Y0) this is the MSDN site it might help you. @Zishan

Answer (score 7):

```
SendMail.CS Page

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;

namespace SendMailUsingWindowsForms
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //Sending the email.
                //Now we must create a new Smtp client to send our email.

                SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);   //smtp.gmail.com // For Gmail
                                                                            //smtp.live.com // Windows live / Hotmail
                                                                            //smtp.mail.yahoo.com // Yahoo
                                                                            //smtp.aim.com // AIM
                                                                            //my.inbox.com // Inbox


                //Authentication.
                //This is where the valid email account comes into play. You must have a valid email account(with password) to give our program a place to send the mail from.

                NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential("*******@gmail.com", "........");

                //To send an email we must first create a new mailMessage(an email) to send.
                MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();

                // Sender e-mail address.
                Msg.From = new MailAddress(textBox1.Text);//Nothing But Above Credentials or your credentials (*******@gmail.com)

                // Recipient e-mail address.
                Msg.To.Add(textBox2.Text);

                // Assign the subject of our message.
                Msg.Subject = textBox3.Text;

                // Create the content(body) of our message.
                Msg.Body = textBox4.Text;

                // Send our account login details to the client.
                client.Credentials = cred;

                //Enabling SSL(Secure Sockets Layer, encyription) is reqiured by most email providers to send mail
                client.EnableSsl = true;

                //Confirmation After Click the Button
                label5.Text = "Mail Sended Succesfully";

                // Send our email.
                client.Send(Msg);



            }
            catch
            {
                // If Mail Doesnt Send Error Mesage Will Be Displayed
                label5.Text = "Error";
            }
        }


    }
}
```

SendMail.Design
[image]

[image]

Comment: This worked for Gmail once I used Port 587, and did so outside of any corporate network/firewall.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

```
    public SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    public MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
    public System.Net.NetworkCredential smtpCreds = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "password");

    public void Send(string sendTo, string sendFrom, string subject, string body)
    {
        try
        {
            //setup SMTP Host Here
            client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            client.Port = 587;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = smtpCreds;
            client.EnableSsl = true;

            //converte string to MailAdress

            MailAddress to = new MailAddress(sendTo);
            MailAddress from = new MailAddress(sendFrom);

            //set up message settings

            msg.Subject = subject;
            msg.Body = body;
            msg.From = from;
            msg.To.Add(to);

            // Enviar E-mail

            client.Send(msg);

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unexpected Error: " + error);
        }
    }
```

dont forget to call:

```
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: Thanks Diogo, but I think this is the same as the code that I've just posted above. It doesn't require a call to System.Windows.Forms though.

Comment: this is working fine with me, try to see if you have your smtp configs correctly.